# Relative screens in titanium apps

Tags: responsive-design, titanium-mobile, platform

I am new to Titanium and I am using alloy.
I developed an app that renders correctly on the emulator with resolution 1200x1920 (Android Nexus 7 Emulator), however the same code when rendered in 768x1280 emulator screen, all my controls are scattered and are not aligned anymore. How can I make the app respond relative to the screen resolution.

(FYI : Genymotion is not working as it shows issues with updating video driver, I will check that later).

My code is like this :

```
var LeftTopView = Ti.UI.createView({
top:'0%',
left:'0%',
height : '30%',
width : '70%',
});

var chkBuy = Ti.UI.createSwitch({
id: 'chkBuy',
left: '2%', 
top:'3%',
value: true,
title:'BUY',
width:'auto',
height:'auto',
color:'Black',
textAlign: Titanium.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT,
style:Ti.UI.Android.SWITCH_STYLE_CHECKBOX,
font:{fontFamily:'Consolas', fontSize: '23dp', fontWeight:'bold',},
});

chkBuy.addEventListener('click',chkBuyClick);

function chkBuyClick(){
chkSell.value = false;  
chkBuy.value = true;;
}

var chkSell = Ti.UI.createSwitch({
id: 'chkSell',
left: '35%',
top:'3%', 
value: false,
title:'SELL',
width:'auto',
height:'auto',
color:'Black',
textAlign: Titanium.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT,
style:Ti.UI.Android.SWITCH_STYLE_CHECKBOX,
font:{fontFamily:'Consolas', fontSize: '23dp', fontWeight:'bold',},
});

chkSell.addEventListener('click',chkSellClick);
function chkSellClick(){
chkBuy.value = false;
chkSell.value = true;
}

LeftTopView.add(chkBuy);
LeftTopView.add(chkSell);

var MainView = Ti.UI.createView({
width:Ti.UI.FILL,
height: Ti.UI.FILL,
left:'0%',
top:'0%',
});

MainView.add(LeftTopView);

var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({
title:'Page2',
backgroundColor:'#000',
exitOnClose:'true',
});

window.add(MainView);
window.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use % in giving top and bottom to the elements(It will cause trouble in orientation) instead use layout. 
checkout the [Documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-layout)